# google+ hangouts store value in state gapi.hangouts.data

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-plus, google-hangouts

I am stuck with slight problem for a while now : Need to store in state a random number, that would persist to all participants.

```
alert(delta[random]);
```

returns value so everything is expected to be ok to this point however that's where mystery starts:

i already tried

```
$.each(gapi.hangout.data.getKeys(),function(i,o){
alert(o);
});
```

but it never enters loop. however if I place

```
alert('dfsdasd');
```

after submitDelta it works.
last two lines

```
    alert(gapi.hangout.data.getValue(random));
    $("#randomNumber").val(gapi.hangout.data.getValue(random));
```

are dead, no alert with 'undefined' or [object].

```
function setRandom()
    {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
        var random = "randomNumber";
        var delta = {};
        delta[random] = JSON.stringify(rand);
        alert(delta[random]);

        gapi.hangout.data.submitDelta(delta);

        alert(gapi.hangout.data.getValue(random));
        $("#randomNumber").val(gapi.hangout.data.getValue(random));
    }
```

i have included 
both libraries
src="//talkgadget.google.com/hangouts/_/api/hangout.js?v=1.1"
and src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"

no handler on onStateChanged

what am I doing wrong here? 
anytime I touch gapi.hangouts.data it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are are two issues here that I see.

The first is that [submitDelta](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.data#gapi.hangout.data.submitDelta) is defined as taking two parameters, and you provide only one.

The other issue is that submitDelta() is asynchronous, so you should not expect getValue() or getState() to work immediately after it is called. The best way to handle things in this case is to register for a StateChangedEvent using onStateChanged.add().

So, for example, you might do something like this:

```
function init(){
    gapi.hangout.data.onStateChanged.add( handleChange );
    submitRandom();
}

function handleChange( stateChangedEvent ){
    var random = "randomNumber";
    var val = gapi.hangout.data.getValue(random);
    alert(val);
    $("#randomNumber").val(val);
}

function submitRandom(){
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    var random = "randomNumber";
    var delta = {};
    delta[random] = JSON.stringify(rand);
    alert(delta[random]);

    gapi.hangout.data.submitDelta(delta, []);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, you have changed tide of battle! Problem was gapi.hangout.data.submitDelta(delta, []); not passing additional array, somehow i thought it was optional.